# Using VNC as a virtual KVM switch

Tags: mac, vnc, kvm-switch

I want to control my laptop from my desktop.

I've been doing this with VNC (PC desktop to MacBook Pro) - but I want to remove the 'viewing' aspect of it on my desktop; I don't want to have the viewing screen on the desktop but still be able to control the mouse/keyboard via VNC.

Is this possible?

I'm using RealVNC Viewer and connecting to the default built-in VNC server on Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of VNC, consider using [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).  A great tool for controlling multiple machines from a single keyboard/mouse.  Cross platform Windows / OSX / Linux.

Comment: Great.  Just so you know, upvoting a useful answer as well as accepting it is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few freeware and/or opensource alternatives for those on a budget.

Windows Only: [Mouse Without Borders](https://blogs.microsoft.com/next/2011/09/09/microsoft-download-from-the-garage-mouse-without-borders/#sm.001gs0g0eozafj011hc19mqjcy045)
OS X Only: [Teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/)

For a cross platform solution there is [x2vnc](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/x2vnc.html) or [Win2VNC](http://fredrik.hubbe.net/win2vnc.html). Which you choose depends on host operating system. The one the mouse/keyboard is connected to. On the machine you wish to control you will need a vnc server, not included, such as [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [OSXVNC](https://sourceforge.net/p/osxvnc/wiki/Home/), [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/), etc... Some may find setup complicated. However it should be pretty straight forward if you have manually configured any sort of VNC setup in the past. The biggest drawback of (x/win)2vnc is connectivity being limited to only 2 systems simultaneously.

Comment: Should also note that synergy is open source & can be found [here](https://github.com/symless/synergy). Though if your intent is to simply compile & use without paying. Morally it would be similar to piracy. The developers work hard & deserve your support.